# XenServer Java API : How to retrieve Xenserver management IP Address

Tags: java, xen

Any help/input/suggestions you can give is greatly appreciated.

We have XenServer 6.0.2 with multiple IPAddresses configured on it but there is only 1 Management Address.

We have Java code that uses Xenserver JAVA API bindings to query Xenserver. We have been using this below code to retrieve the management ip address of all the xenserver in a pool.

```
           Map<Host, Host.Record> hypervisors = Host.getAllRecords(getConnection());

    for (Host.Record hypRecord : hypervisors.values()) {
        String mgmtIP = hypRecord.address;
                      .........
                      .........
            }
```

This code worked in our lab but testing at a partner site has revealed problem with this code. The Ipaddress returned is different from the management ip address? For example, at partner site, the xenserver had 3 IPs configured on the box . Lets cal it ip1, ip2 and ip3. We used ip1 to issue xen api request and to login and it worked fine. But the value for variable "mgmtIP" returned in above code is ip2. This is making me think :
a. Can there be more than one management ip for a single xenserver?
b. Wouln't  the line"String mgmtIP = hypRecord.address;" in above code return management ip ?
b. Shouldn't the xen api request be always send to the management ip address (of the master if in pool) ?
c. What is the best way to retrieve the management ip address of a xenserver?
    Since we are on 6.0.2, the method : 
          public PIF getManagementIface(Connection c) on class Host

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using xe:

```
user@host ~# IFS=,; for uuid in $(xe pif-list management=true --minimal); do echo -n   "$uuid -> "; xe pif-param-get param-name=IP uuid=$uuid; done
12334567-1234-1234-1234-123456787890 -> x.x.x.x
12334567-1234-1234-1234-123456787890 -> x.x.x.x
12334567-1234-1234-1234-123456787890 -> x.x.x.x
12334567-1234-1234-1234-123456787890 -> x.x.x.x
```

using api you will query the same logic
http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.0.0/1.0/en_gb/api/?c=PIF
For pif on host,
Does pif have management true?
Get IP

Another trick which might be useful to you is

```
user@host ~# xe host-param-get uuid=12334567-1234-1234-1234-123456787890 param-name=address
x.x.x.x
```

http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.0.0/1.0/en_gb/api/?c=host